# Why am I getting “TypeError: Cannot read property 'education' of null” when using newEdu or deleteEdu?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, web-development-server, nodejs-server

I've been trying to add new data to the education part of my database using this method

**Controller**

```
newUserEdu: async (req, res, next) => {
        const user = await User.findById(req.value.body.user)

        const newEdu = req.value.body;
        delete newEdu.user;

        const edu = new Edu(newEdu);
        edu.users = user;

        await edu.save();

        user.education.push(edu);
        await user.save();

        res.status(200).json(edu);

    },

deleteEdu: async(req, res, next) => {
        const { eduId } = req.value.params;

        const edu = await Edu.findById(eduId);
        if( !edu ){
            return res.status(404).json({error: 'Field Non-Existent'});
        }

        const userID = edu.users;

        const user = await User.findById(userID);

        await edu.remove();

        user.education.pull(edu);
        await user.save();

        res.status(200).json({success: true});
    }
```

The models of the respective user and the education are the following

**User Model**

```
 username: String,
    password: String,
    name: String,
    gender: String,
    dob: Date,
    email: String,
    contact: String,
    education: [{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'edu'
    }]
```

**Education Model**

```
const eduSchema = new Schema({
    institute: String,
    program: String,
    start: Number,
    end: Number,
    field: String,
    users: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    }
});
```

Postman gives out this error which alludes to the line containing push()

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'education' of null
    at newUserWrk (G:\Learning\University\Web Tech-II\Projects\scala2\NodeJS\controllers\wrk.controller.js:20:14)
```

Comment: `user` is only defined after the `await User.findById()` but before that it's `undefined`. So if you placed that line with `push()` within a condition e.g. `if (!user) {...}`, you should be good. Let me know.

Comment: I tried checking with the console.log() to see if the parameters are being passed and they  are but it's not being assigned to const user = await User.findById(req.value.body.user)

Comment: Then try using `let` instead of `const` statement